# comm command to get common data from file1 file2

Tags: php, linux, shell

I want to get common data present in file1 and file2.

```
<?php 
    $cmd="comm -12 <(sort /Source/20-07-2015/file1 | uniq) <(sort /Source/20-07-2015/file2 | uniq) > /20-07-2015/commondata_20072015-248932-ac.csv";
    $result =exec($cmd);
 ?>
```

but above code is throwing an error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: can you try with $result=exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd))

Comment: `/bin/sh` doesn't support process substitution. You need to use `/bin/bash` (probably manually).

Comment: deepak i had tried with this but it gives comm: extra operand `|'
Try `comm --help' for more information.
error

Comment: Etan this is php code please suggest how could i do it in php...same i had tried in shell it works if i execute ./scrip.sh....but how could i do it here..

Comment: is there any alternate way to get common data from two files in php

Comment: Etan is there something you can suggest for same..

Comment: I am having trouble reconciling the code with the error. The code is PHP code. The error is an SH parser error. So, it appears that the person wrote some PHP code and, instead of running it with PHP, ran it with SH. That won't work.

Comment: Kainaw exec() function in php execute linux commands in php and return string output.

Answer (score 0):

PHP `exec()` uses `sh` and `sh` does not support `<(...)`.

The simplest fix (from someone who knows `sh`/`bash` but not PHP) is to have `sh` invoke `bash` to run your command:

```
$cmd="bash -c 'comm -12 <(sort /Source/20-07-2015/file1 | uniq) <(sort /Source/20-07-2015/file2 | uniq) > /20-07-2015/commondata_20072015-248932-ac.csv'";
```